# How to convert base64 String to image and stored in django model?

Tags: python, django-models, base64

I'm converting an image to a Base64 string and sending it from android device to the server. Now, I need to change that string back to an image and save it in the database which is Django model

```
import base64
imgdata = base64.b64decode(imgstring)
filename = 'some_image.jpg'  # I assume you have a way of picking unique filenames
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(imgdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`image = np.asarray(Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgstring)))`